# Scaling with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I've implemented scaling into our window where we are modifying the scale transform like so:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ScaleTransform x:Key="windowScaleTransform" 
                        ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

We are using Caliburn Micro, and this works fine for our main window.

When I've copied the same code and made sure the actual ScaleX/Y properties get updated in other windows, the windows don't seem to be listening to the scale transform. Again, this is only for windows that are newly initialised, like a settings window.

In our MainWindowViewModel, we initialise an AboutBox like this:

```cs
windowManager.ShowDialog(new AboutBoxViewModel(aboutBoxService), null, null);
```

But the about box, even though it has that window.resource code, does not seem to care about it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point...

Comment: You may add the code where the resource `windowScaleTransform` is used.

Comment: hey Orace, I'm not using `windowScaleTransform` anywhere else in the XAML file so that key name is redundant so you can probably ignore it has one. I'm using the same code in other window XAMLs but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful but for some reason, scaling wasn't happening on other windows when I had the above code in the `Window.Resources` section.

What worked is finding the first element of the Window/UserControl, and adding the scaling like so. In my case, one of the windows had a border as its first element:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SeeColour}">
    <Border.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Source={x:Static mediators:ScalingMediator.Instance}, Path = ScaleX}" 
                        ScaleY="{Binding Source={x:Static mediators:ScalingMediator.Instance}, Path = ScaleY}" />
    </Border.LayoutTransform>
... etc
```

Hope this helps other people :)